# Failed to Attach DB on replicated SAN

Tags: sql, mysql-replication, disaster-recovery, msdtc

We currently have a clustered SQL Server 2005 which has replicated SAN disks for our DR solution, to test DR we break the SAN synch and then attach the various DB's on the DR server.

Our web servers recently had an application upgrade where the version of Dot Net moved from v1.1 to V4 but the SQL servers were not upgraded to Dot Net 4.

On a DR test we broke the SAN synch as usual and then proceeded to attach the DB's but one of the DB's failed to attach with the following error:

```
An error occurred while recovering database 'xxxxxxxxxx'. Unable to connect to Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC) to check the completion status of transaction (1:288343130). Fix MS DTC, and run recovery again.
Could not open new database 'xxxxxxxxx'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 3437)
```

In the SQL log found the following:

```
SQL Server detected a DTC/KTM in-doubt transaction with UOW {7DF9C2C2-EEBA-4842-B520-7428029E1E8E}.Please resolve it following the guideline for Troubleshooting DTC Transactions.
```

During the recovery of the DB it had completed at least 60% of the attach process and had rolled forward 1600+ transactions but found the 1 in-doubt transaction.

This seems to be a problem which has been encountered by certain people before but on the same server not in our DR type solution, the resolutions in this case would not apply.

We have carried out this DR test on numerous occasions in the past without encountering this problem, we have tried this 3 times since the application upgrade and have encountered the error twice.

Any experience or assistance in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since your other databases came up as usual, you can rule out a storage problem. I searched for the error text you quote and found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa275795%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) on Microsoft's site, which suggests it might be fixable with a simple command.